# Python Error - 'str' object has no attribute '_geom'

Tags: python, point, shapely, geom

I am using `shapely` to convert longitudes and latitudes contained in a CSV to WKB format.
For context, the CSV is parsed using a python AWS Lambda code.

The format of the file being parsed is as follows:

| Name | Comments | Yes/No | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test_1 | This is a test | Yes | 56.872993679521244 | -4.141840954280135 |
| Test_2 | This is a test | No | 55.20394960316738 | -2.5378432182396935 |

I have then tried to convert these to WKB by calling the longtiude/latitude columns

```
g = ('Point(longitude, latitude)')
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print (new)
```

but I am getting the error `'str' object has no attribute '_geom'`

How can I overcome this? The CSV has 100s of rows and I don't want to have to convert each long/lat individually - I just wanted to call the two columns and it would produce the WKB for each point.

Comment: Post the full error.

Comment: Your code sets `g` to a string value. But `dumps()` is expecting a `Point` object. I think you might mean `g = Point(longitude, latitude)` without enclosing quotes. I'm puzzled why you thought it needed quotes.

Comment: @BoarGules because it tells me point isn't defined if I try ```g = Point(longitude, latitude)```

Comment: You need to add `from shapely.geometry import Point` at the top of your script, then remove the quotes from around `g = ('Point(longitude, latitude)')` so it's `g = Point(longitude, latitude)` or maybe yet something else, such as a list of `Point`s?

Comment: that solves the ```Point is not defined``` issue but then I get the error that ```longtiude is not defined```, so I done ```g = Point('longitude', 'latitude')``` but now there is an error ```must be real number, not str```

Comment: Putting quotes around variable names may make the error message go away but it won't solve your problem. `longitude is not defined` is telling you very straightforwardly that somewhere before that your code must *assign* a value to `longitude`, like this: `longitude = -4.141840954280135`. If you don't have that, or something equivalent, `shapely` won't have any numbers to work with. I think you may need to spend a couple of hours working through this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the column values to `Point` function as following-

```
def calculate_wkb(lon, lat):
    g = Point(lon, lat)
    new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
    return new

df['wkb'] = df.apply(lambda x: calculate_wkb(x.Longitude, x.Latitude), axis=1)
```

Comment: how can I ensure all my columns are included in the data frame? Thanks :)

Comment: Edited my answer.  This will add a new column to your existing dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the point definition to wkt before converting to wkb, additionally coordinates must be separated by blank space, not colon.

```
from shapely import wkb
from shapely import wkt

g = wkt.loads('Point(-4.141840954280135 56.872993679521244)')
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print (new)
```

Comment: I don't want to convert each point individually though. Is there not a way to do this for all the entries in the longitude and latitude columns?

Comment: i wrote the values instead of longitude and latitude variables for illustration purposes only, you can substitute them in your code without a problem (i guess).

Comment: Thats what I have tried and it doesn't work unfortunately. It throws the above error